# Singularity and numba/numpy: RuntimeError: Attempted to compile AOT function without the compiler used by `numpy.distutils` present

Tags: numba, python-3.10, singularity-container

My software is written in Python and uses numba and numpy. I distribute it using Docker.

Here is the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/MrTomRod/scoary-2/blob/master/Dockerfile).

One of my users (see GitHub [issue](https://github.com/MrTomRod/scoary-2/issues/3)) wants to run the software on a HPC where Singularity is used instead of Docker. He gets the following error message:

```bash
$ singularity pull docker://troder/scoary-2
$ singularity run scoary-2_latest.sif scoary2 --help
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/bin/scoary2", line 5, in <module>
      from scoary.scoary import main
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scoary/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
      from .scoary import scoary
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scoary/scoary.py", line 7, in <module>
      from .analyze_trait import analyze_trait, worker
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scoary/analyze_trait.py", line 7, in <module>
      from fast_fisher.fast_fisher_numba import odds_ratio, test1t as fisher_exact_two_tailed
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fast_fisher/fast_fisher_numba.py", line 5, in <module>
      cc = CC('fast_fisher_compiled')
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/pycc/cc.py", line 65, in __init__
      self._toolchain = Toolchain()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/pycc/platform.py", line 78, in __init__
      self._raise_external_compiler_error()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/pycc/platform.py", line 121, in _raise_external_compiler_error
      raise RuntimeError(msg)
  RuntimeError: Attempted to compile AOT function without the compiler used by `numpy.distutils` present. If using conda try:
  
  #> conda install gcc_linux-64 gxx_linux-64
```

On my HPC's Singularity, it works without issue. What is different? How to debug or solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not enough to install `gcc` and `python-devel`, it also required `gcc-c++`! (Fedora)